# How to create a new string without spaces from another string using a loop

Tags: c++, string, loops

I started off trying to write a function that would delete spaces from a string, but now that I've looked at a host of other peoples' solutions to that problem, I'm more just trying to understand exactly what went wrong in my code/why the `std::cout << t << std::endl;` at the end doesn't output anything.

When I included `std::cout << t[count];` during the loop (the statement that is commented out below) it correctly would output to the console: `hereissometext` without spaces. When I have `std::cout << t[0] << std::endl;` at the end, it correctly outputs `h`, `t[1]` as `e`, `t[2]` as `r`, and so on. However, when I try to output `t` at the end, it outputs blank space, and `t.size()` outputs `0`.

I am fairly new to coding so forgive me if this is a completely obvious question.

```
    std::string s = "here is some text";
    std::string t = "";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (std::isalpha(s[i])) {
            t[count]+=s[i];
            // std::cout << t[count];
            count++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << t << std::endl;
```

Comment: Do you _absolutely need_ a copy, can't you do this in-place? I'm asking because that will cut down runtime by a factor of about one million, by avoiding repeated reallocations for countless `push_back()` operations. Not so much an issue for an 18-character string like above, but for 18,000 or 18,000,000 characters, or when doing this many times... Something like, uh, `std::erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());` or... similar?  Even if you do need a copy, making a copy first and then stripping in-place is probably better...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have undefined behavior in your loop, as you insert into a `std::string` using its `operator[]` without making sure it has the right size. You can instead use

```
t.push_back(s[i]);
```

which not only inserts a `char`, but also makes sure the internal buffer is (re-)allocated when it's too small for the new string.

Note further that you don't really need the `count` variable. `std::string` always keeps track of its length, so `t.size()` will always yield the value of your current `count` (once you fix the UB of course).

As an aside, copying the parts of a sequence that match a certain criterion is a common task, and there exists a specific library template that does exactly this and frees you from a hand-crafted loop:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy_if(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), std::back_inserter(t),
     [](char c){ return std::isalpha(c); });
```

Finally, also note the comment by @MatthieurFoltzer on the behavior of `std::isalpha`, which might be worth taking into account.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good. You already point out some improvement, so you may also explain that std::isalpha will not only discard space, but all non-alphabetic char. It will not work if there's special characters different from space.

Comment: In your aside, there is no need to define a lambda. Just put `::isalpha` as predicate of `std::copy_if` (you may use the C version, since `std::isalpha` has overloads).

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani True, but note that it's generally not possible to take the address of functions in the standard library - it's forbidden unless stated otherwise. While it may be allowed for `::isalpha`, I think it's often good to not even come close to such illegal constructs.

Answer (score 6):

```
t[count]+=s[i];
```

This doesn't work like that. With this you can change existing characters of the string. But since your string is empty, that causes undefined behavior. To append to the string, change that line to this instead:

```
t += s[i];
```

And it'll print the desired output of `hereissometext`. You can find the documentation of the `+=` operator for strings [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to not use a hand crafted loop. You can use `std::copy_if` in combination with a lambda expression to formulate your condition. This will be more stable than your implementation (what happens if the length of your string `s` exceeds the capacity of an `int`?). I think it also enhances the readability.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "here is some text";
    std::string t = "";
    auto comp = [&](const char c) { return std::isalpha(c); };
    std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(t), comp);

    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```